# Unable to pull from GCR registry using docker engine-api and long lived JSON file

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry, docker-api

In the advanced authentication methods documentation for google cloud container registry explains a method for login to the registry using a JSON Key file with the docker cli, this just works fine

> $ docker login -u _json_key -p "$(cat keyfile.json)" https://gcr.io

However I'm trying to use that same keyfile.json file to login to the registry using the golang `docker/engine-api` libraries, I have some working code that this seems to be authenticating fine into other registryies, but always providing a file with the following structure

```
{
  "auths": {
    "cr.whatever.com": {
      "password": "PASSWORD",
      "username": "registry"
    }
  }
}
```

By passing that `Unmarshal` file into `ImageBuildOptions` function [here](https://github.com/docker/engine-api/blob/4290f40c056686fcaa5c9caf02eac1dde9315adf/client/image_build.go#L23) to then be consumed [here](https://github.com/docker/engine-api/blob/4290f40c056686fcaa5c9caf02eac1dde9315adf/client/image_build.go#L34)

However is not working when using the `keyfile.json` or a working `config.json` ...

The docker documentation states that a JSON base64 encoded object with username and password should be used as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.32/#operation/ImageBuild) into the Header Parameters section.

I've tried multiple option to produce a file that can be successfully consumed into the docker `X-Registry-Config` header without much luck...

Any help/hint would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your help [jsand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6135774/jsand), I finally draft a working code function as below

```
func (d *DockerEngineClient) BuildImage(archive, modelId string, authConfigs map[string]types.AuthConfig) (types.ImageBuildResponse, error) {
    buildContext, err := os.Open(archive)
    defer buildContext.Close()

    c, err := ioutil.ReadFile(os.Getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_FILE"))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var authConfigs2 map[string]types.AuthConfig
    authConfigs2 = make(map[string]types.AuthConfig)

    authConfigs2["gcr.io"] = types.AuthConfig{
        Username: "_json_key",
        Password: string(c),
        ServerAddress: fmt.Sprintf("https://%s", d.remoteRegistryPrefix),
    }

    buildOptions := types.ImageBuildOptions{
        Tags:        []string{fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", d.remoteRegistryPrefix, modelId)},
        AuthConfigs: authConfigs2,
    }

    var buildResponse types.ImageBuildResponse

    buildResponse, err = d.client.ImageBuild(context.TODO(), buildContext, buildOptions)
    if err != nil {
        return buildResponse, err
    }

    b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(buildResponse.Body)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", b)
    buildResponse.Body.Close()

    return buildResponse, err
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that 'config' is an overloaded term. Looks like `X-Registry-Config` contains a base64-encoded version of the JSON-encoded value of options.AuthConfigs, rather than the full docker config file. If you only want to authenticate for `https://gcr.io`, your JSON input should be:

```
{
  "gcr.io": {
    "username": "_json_key",
    "password": "{contents of keyfile.json}"
  }
}
```

Or, if you're willing to use Docker's golang libs:

```
import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/docker/engine-api/types"
)

def addDockerAuthsHeader(keyfile_contents string, headers http.Header) error {
    authConfigs := map[string]types.AuthConfig{
        "gcr.io": {
            Username: "_json_key",
            Password: keyfile_contents
        }
    }

    buf, err := json.Marshal(authConfigs)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    headers.Add("X-Registry-Config", base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(buf))

    return nil
}
```

Generating `keyfile_contents` is left as an exercise for the reader :)